# user input filtering in c language like avoiding alphabets and symbols

Tags: c, input, filter

i need to calculate the age then in c programming how can i do "user input filtering" at scanf.

```
 main()
 {
 scanf("%d %d %d ,month,date, year);
 --------;
 printf("your age is"...);
 }
```

here the user can enter alphabets or some symbols how to filter them in c?

Comment: You need to break the reading and converting into 2 separate steps. `fgets()` (NOT `gets()` because it unavoidably creates a buffer overflow opportunity) to read in the input, then try several attempts at parsing it, either by looking at individual characters, or using `sscanf()`.  But this is very error-prone, and I'm certain there are libraries out there for parsing dates that will be more reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by filtering, you mean remove the offending characters, you can either read lines in buffers and inspect them, or use a quick hack like this:

```
scanf("%d%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d", &month, &day, &year);
```

where the `*` after `%` means to read and throw away and the `^0-9` in brackets means any character that is not 0 through 9. Possible pitfall: if the first character is unwanted, `scanf` fails. If you put a `%*[^0-9]` in the beginning, then input beginning with a number fails.

Alternatively, ask the user for proper input in case of failure (in previous case also you should check for the return value of `scanf`):

```
while (scanf("%d %d %d", &month, &day, &year) != 3)
{
    printf("bad input! Retry\n");
    /* possibly flush the line: */
    while (!feof(stdin) && fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
}
```

Comment: thankx bro working ...want to vote your answer up...but i cant

Comment: sorry still we can enter values like 123213ew thats accepted no error msg returned

Comment: ok solved it ..                                              scanf("%d%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]", &month, &day, &year);

Comment: @WifuWifu, I'm not sure adding `%*[^0-9]` would be such a good idea as it would consume everything left in the input until a digit. You should check the output of `scanf` against 3. With input such as 123213ew, `scanf` only reads one number, then waits for more numbers (even if you already pressed enter, you can still enter more numbers).

Comment: i dont understand checking scanf for 3...pls explain

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of items successfully read. Like the `while` loop I have written above, you should compare the return value of `scanf` with 3, to make sure you have actually read 3 items or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for - You can use the `atoi` function to convert the user input into an integer and check if they are valid integers.

Comment: but how we check the validity of integers afters converting the user input to integers??

Comment: @WifuWifu: You can't.  You have to read in the string first, so that if it turns out *not* to be integers, you can try parsing it a different way.